# How to check login first before render layout view in Marionettejs?

Tags: javascript, marionette

In marionettejs layout view, I'd like to check if user is lgoin (Async), then only render the layout if user is login, or go to login url.

The challenge is that api call is async, and by the time api fetched the data, the page is already rendered in browser. In Marionettejs layout render is automatic. Here is my code:

```
var DashboardLayout = Mn.LayoutView.extend({
    initialize: function () {
    },
    el: '#app-container',
    template: require('./dashboard.layout.html'),
    regions: {
        /* Building region is only trigger during the new */
    },
    onBeforeRender: function () {
        var thisView = this; 
        api.company.getInfo() // get some data to see if user is login
            .then(function(result){

                if(result.code !== 2000) {
                    // not login, or can't find user
                    Backbone.history.navigate('/login', true);
                } else {
                    appData.company = result.company;
                }
                console.log(appData);
            });
    },
    onRender: function () {
        this.addRegion('nav', '#vs-nav-region');
        this.addRegion('header', '#vs-header-region');
        this.addRegion('content', '#vs-content-region');
        this.addRegion('modal', '#vs-modal');

        var ss = new Nav();
        var navRegion = this.getRegion('nav');

        navRegion.show(ss);

    }
});
```

I fetched data in onBeforeRender, and I want to only render the layout if user is login.

But Layout render is automatic, out of my control. I think this is a common challenge in Marionettejs app. Is there a pattern to address this problem?

Comment: Could you do your check inside onRender() function. So that you could render some stub before the check and then render whatever you want after check is passed?

Comment: @anvk onRender() is called when rending is complete, so no good. http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.itemview.html#render--onrender-event

Comment: if you are using controllers, you can do this in controller before showing the layoutView or you can do it in router

Comment: The ideal flow as per my understanding is router(redirect to another router if not authorised for this route) -> controller(if authorised route) -> module -> layout -> view

Comment: I see. You are right, authentication checking should be done in router, the views. Views are just for rendering.